# MySQL - Order by in Inner query. What am I missing?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join, subquery

I have the following tables and relations:

```
Players:
foreign_key to User  

Users:
foreign_key to City

Cities:
latitude (float)
longitude (float)
```

I am trying to get all the Professors which associated User is from a given city or near_by city.

I have this query, which returns me the near_by (20km) cities given a particular latitude and longitude and the distance to the given city latitude and longitude. In this case `latitude = 41.353312 and longitude = 1.976252`:

```
SELECT cities.*,
 6371 *
 acos(cos(radians(41.353312)) *
 cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
 cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(1.976252)) +
 sin(radians(41.353312))*sin(radians(cities.latitude)))
 AS km_away FROM `cities` GROUP BY km_away ASC HAVING km_away <= 20
```

And I have tried this query (**which doesn't work**) which I would like it to return me the players which associated user city is near by the given city (latitude and longitude).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `players` 
INNER JOIN `users` 
    ON `users`.`id` = `players`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN `cities` 
    ON `cities`.`id` = `users`.`city_id`
WHERE 
(
    cities.id IN 
     (SELECT cities.*,
             6371 *
             acos(cos(radians(41.353312)) *
             cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
             cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(1.976252)) +
             sin(radians(41.353312))*sin(radians(cities.latitude))) AS km_away 
        FROM `cities` 
        GROUP BY km_away ASC 
        HAVING km_away <= 20)
)
```

I would also like to:

1 - Get the players ordered by the distance of its associated user city to the given city.

2 - Get the distance (value) in each record returned.

Comment: +1. (just for the great circle calculation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what result set you want to return. But looking at your problem, I think you want to have your subquery ( +1!  for the "great circle distance" calculation of distance from Barcelona!) as a rowsource.

One approach is to use the subquery as an "inline view", rather than reference it in the WHERE clause.

Since that query is returning all columns from the cities table, it can basically replace the cities table in the query.

The GROUP BY clause is not needed. It's only going to serve to eliminate rows from the result set when two cities are equidistant from the given latitude/longitude. (I don't believe that's the behavior you want, it's not wrong to want that, but it would be very unusual.)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `players` 
INNER JOIN `users` 
    ON `users`.`id` = `players`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT cities.*,
         6371 *
         acos(cos(radians(41.353312)) *
         cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
         cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(1.976252)) +
         sin(radians(41.353312))*sin(radians(cities.latitude))) AS km_away 
    FROM `cities` 
    HAVING km_away <= 20
    ORDER BY km_away
 ) `cd` 
    ON `cd`.`id` = `users`.`city_id`
```

NOTE: I've given that inline view an alias of `cd` (which I read as shorthand for city distance.

The COUNT aggregate is going to return only one row, so no ORDER BY is necessary. If you change the SELECT list, and want rows to be returned in a specific order, add an ORDER BY on the outermost query, e.g.

```
ORDER BY cd.km_away ASC
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You should be able to reference any columns from the `cities`, `players`, `users` tables, as well as the calculated distance (`km_away`) in the SELECT list. Of course, you would specify the columns you want returned, rather than using the '.*'.  But `cd.km_away' will be available to be referenced in the outer query (SELECT list, WHERE clause, ORDER BY, etc.)

```
SELECT cd.km_away
     , cd.*
     , players.*
     , users.*
FROM `players` 
INNER JOIN `users` 
    ON `users`.`id` = `players`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT cities.*,
         6371 *
         acos(cos(radians(41.353312)) *
         cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
         cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(1.976252)) +
         sin(radians(41.353312))*sin(radians(cities.latitude))) AS km_away 
    FROM `cities` 
    HAVING km_away <= 20
    ORDER BY km_away
 ) `cd` 
    ON `cd`.`id` = `users`.`city_id`
 ORDER BY cd.km_away
```

Comment: And as your comment on `GROUP BY` describes, I think you'd want `WHERE` rather than `HAVING`. No objection to your answer, but isn't this fundamentally the same as my downvoted answer?

Comment: I don't know why did I write COUNT(*). I actually would like to get all the professors fields plus the associated users fields, plus the city fields plus the calculated distance of the given distance...I can do SELECT professors.* , but I fail to see how to get the km_away for each professor record returned.

Comment: @shawnt: yes, this looks basically the same as the last query in your answer. i didn't downvote your answer. but i think the downvote may have to do with the earliest part of your answer.

Comment: I didn't figure it was you. The downvote appeared after I added more detail. Also I hate to take away from your answer, but it's non-standard to refer to column aliases in the having clause and ordering should only be applied to the final result set. By all means use the extensions if they're helpful but I wasn't trying to be rude.

Comment: @Hommer: updated my answer to reference columns from each of the tables. I'm not clear on the `professors` part of your question, I don't see any reference to anything like that in your query, I'm sure I'm just missing it.

Comment: @shawnt00: yes, this looks basically the same as the last query in your answer. In this case, we can use the `HAVING` to reference the derived value... that expression is not available early in the query for filtering which rows to process (which is what the WHERE clause does), that predicate has to be evaluated AFTER all the rows are processed. We use the `HAVING` clause because it gets processed almost last in the query (just before the ORDER BY and the LIMIT). Plus, I think it's better to reference the alias for the GCD expression rather than repeat that expression multiple times.

Comment: @Hommer, try that last query in my answer (it's going to return more columns that you want, and return the `km_away` twice... and please let me know if this isn't the result set you were looking for.

Comment: I understand the desire to avoid repeating the expression. But isn't that a non-issue if the filtering and ordering is done in the outer query? The only real purpose of the inline view is to augment the cities table and create that named derived column.

Comment: @shawnt00: the slight advantage of the HAVING clause in the subquery rather than as an equivalent WHERE clause on the outer query is that MySQL won't write the unneeded rows into the temporary MyISAM table (which MySQL uses to materialize that inline view.) MySQL won't "push" a `km_away <` predicate on the outer query into the inline view. (To be fair, there's all those cases of OUTER joins and ORs, so it's not a simple matter of determining whether it's safe to push a predicate into a view or not.)

Answer (score 1):

You got ASC on a GROUP BY clause. You mean to use ORDER BY.

**EDIT**
Excuse my ignorance of mysql. I prefer to stick with the standard approaches especially when they're also the easiest ones. OP noted in bold text "which doesn't work" and before reading the entire question, I believed that my answer original answer was likely the problem.

```
SELECT
    6371 *
    acos(cos(radians(41.353312)) *
    cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
    cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(1.976252)) +
    sin(radians(41.353312))*sin(radians(cities.latitude))) as km,
    ...
FROM
    players
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = players. user_id
    INNER JOIN cities ON cities.id = users.city_id
WHERE 
    6371 *
    acos(cos(radians(41.353312)) *
    cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
    cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(1.976252)) +
    sin(radians(41.353312))*sin(radians(cities.latitude)))
    <= 20
ORDER BY
    6371 *
    acos(cos(radians(41.353312)) *
    cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
    cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(1.976252)) +
    sin(radians(41.353312))*sin(radians(cities.latitude)))
    ASC
```

A derived table/virtual table/inline view cleans it up a bit.

```
SELECT cities.km, ...
FROM
    players
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = players. user_id
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            cities.*, /* don't know if this works on mysql */
            6371 *
            acos(cos(radians(41.353312)) *
            cos(radians(cities.latitude)) *
            cos(radians(cities.longitude) - radians(1.976252)) +
            sin(radians(41.353312))*sin(radians(cities.latitude))) as km
        ) as cities /* maybe another name is appropriate */
        ON cities.id = users.city_id
WHERE cities.km <= 20
ORDER BY cities.km ASC
```

Comment: Well I haven't even looked at your query, but apparently mysql is even weirder than I thought.

Comment: @shant00: it's a MySQL-specific extension that allows the `ASC` and `DESC` keywords following `GROUP BY` expressions.

Comment: I suspected something like that, but since you really only expect one row per group, why not just user order by?

Comment: @shawnt00: I added a +1 vote on your answer. You might consider rewording your original thoughts about what the OP meant to do, mentioning that the use of the ASC and DESC keyword on GROUP BY is a MySQL-specific extension to ANSI SQL, and where the use of such an extension doesn't gain you anything, the usage is probably best avoided. Something along those lines.

Comment: @shawnt00: the `km <= 20` predicate could be included in the inline view. Without a predicate on this expression, MySQL is going to basically create a copy of the entire `cities` table when it materializes the view into a temporary MyISAM table. Any predicate (even a HAVING clause) that filters out rows is going to result in a smaller temporary table.

Comment: @spencer7593 Yeah, I always debate about editing away the history of my answer. I do appreciate the comments on mysql implementation and you are apparently knowledgeable about that system. In general I will still apply the portable, more declarative methods though I will probably hesitate to try contributing to mysql questions.

Comment: @shawnt00: I don't think there's anything wrong with improving my answers. I note my changes with `<b>UPDATE:</b>` and will use `<strike></strike>` tags to mark out what I want to retract. I think that strikes a good balance (ha! see what i did there?) between leaving my previous <strike>blunder</strike> viewable, and allowing for an improved answer.